# Best practices to migrate to version 2 of a type with Json.NET during an upgrade

Tags: c#, json.net

Currently we have a type with an attribute to signal which properties must be encrypted before persisting the data to disk. We use reflection to see what properties are decorated with ConfidentialAttribute, encrypt the values and then serialize. On a deserialization we decrypt the ConfidentialAttribute decorated properties. Here is a simplified example of what the type looks like.

```
class MyObject_V1
{
    [Confidential]
    public string StringData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

We are doing some refactoring/clean up and plan to get rid of the ConfidentialAttribute and use something like this.

```
class MyObject_V2
{
    public ConfidentialString StringData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class ConfidentialString
{
    [OnSerializing]
    public void Serialize(StreamingContext context)
    {
        //Encrypt value...
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void Deserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        //Decrypt value...
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

We have a requirement to maintain configuration data during an upgrade. My question is what is the best practice for migrating the configuration of MyObject_V1 persisted to disk to MyObject_V2 persisted to disk. Some options I am thinking of are having the classes live side by side or perhaps having both properties live side by side with some logic to do the migration once the object is accessed for the first time.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not sure but you might be able to use AutoMapper, thats usually how we handle versioning. No idea how it handles serialization though

Answer (score 1):

You can use our migrations framework

https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

This test file gives good examples of using the framework

https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net/blob/master/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Spec/HashBasedDataMigratorSpec.cs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, it should be very easy. So easy you won't have to do anything!

`MyObject_V1` should produce the exact same output when serialized as `MyObject_V2`. So a `MyObject_V1` serialized before the change should deserialize into a `MyObject_V2` without any modification. You just need to implement the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods correctly.

Also, this is the very best practice possible: keep total backward compatibility, and make your refactoring only affect implementation détails. if you can keep your configuration files the same way while refactoring your code, do so.

To sum up: the best way to migrate data is not having to migrate it at all!